# Coding hollow square in c++ with nested for loop and if statement

Tags: c++

So for a lab project the goal is to print out shapes using a "*."
The four basic shapes are a square, two downwards pointing right triangles, and a hollow square. Everything seems to be working fine for any integer I input but I'm not entirely sure I'm doing the loop for the hollow square correctly and would like it if someone could give me some advice.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout; using std::endl; using std::cin;

int main()
{
    cout << "Input arbitrary integer ";
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        for (int j = n; j >= i; j--)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        for (int j = 2; j <= i; j++)
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
        for (int j = n; j >= i; j--)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            if (i == 1)
                cout << "*";
            else if (j == 1)
                cout << "*";
            else if (i == n)
                cout << "*";
            else if (j == n)
                cout << "*";
            else
                cout << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you state a more specific question, other than just "I need help"?

Comment: If your code is working correctly it is generally off-topic here.  If there is a problem, specify your input, the incorrect output, and the desired output.

Comment: Basically it's right. However, there's no need for so many `else if`s. Just use the logical OR operator in a single if statement (`||`). Another approach would be to replace the entire body of the inner for loop with this: `cout << ((i==1||i==n||j==1||j==n)?"*":" ");`. But since compilers today are very clever, any of these (including your own solution) would produce pretty much the same, or equally as good binaries, so these shouldn't really make a difference at runtime.

Comment: Add a comment. Add comments.

Comment: Thanks for the advice adam10603, I just wanted to make sure that I wasn't messing anything up. I cleaned it up using your suggestion and now I feel confident in submitting it. Thanks again!